# What causes Internet Explorers icon to flicker?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

When I browse to my website, when the JavaScript loads, it takes a while. During that time, the Internet Explorer icon goes wild. It keeps flickering between the blue (loading icon) and the cursor.

What am I doing wrong?

This happens a lot. Especially when I try to type text within a `textarea`.

Comment: What is happening (computationally) whenever you're typing in the textbox? Is there a lot of javascript being dynamically executed and sent back to the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try setting your own [cursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358795.aspx), but I suspect IE will keep on changing the cursor out from underneath you.

What I suspect is happening (without a repro link) is that you have lots of little resources—jscript files, css files, etc—that each download separately.  You could try combining all your resources.

Or you have some script that is doing something wonky in the AJAX world and you need to bundle all your requests tighter.